# Can't see Xml comments from external assembly

Tags: .net-core, swagger, nswag

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API using NSwag.AspNetCore (12.0.13). The controller methods in the project have been decorated with Xml comments and the project itself has been configured appropriately (below) to capture those comments. The Swagger UI displays those comments as expected and all is well.

The project references an external assembly which is the product of an dotnet core classlib project. That project also has controller methods decorated with Xml comments and is also configured appropriately (below) to capture those comments. The Swagger UI displays those controller methods inline with those in the host project but it does NOT display the Xml comments.

Any ideas what might be the cause of that condition? Does something else need to be done to combine generated documentation files in separate Swagger-aware assemblies?

`<PropertyGroup>...
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
...
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: Is there an `external.assembly.name.xml` file present in the deployment dir?

Comment: Thanks @T2PS, that's it. I should have mentioned the external assembly is coming in via nuget and although the package has the xml file it's not making it to the hosting app's bin folder. Seems like that should happen automatically. Any chance you've seen/fixed that behavior?

Comment: No fix yet, but it is an issue on our radar -- we supply a package that should have its XMLDoc propagated in the way you're expecting, so I expect this affects us as well. I'll update if we find anything.